# Python 3, UnicodeEncodeError with decode set to ignore

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, encoding, utf-8

This code makes an http call to a solr index.

```
query_uri = prop.solr_base_uri + "?q=" + query + "&wt=json&indent=true"
with urllib.request.urlopen(query_uri) as response:
    data = response.read()
    #data is bytes
    data_str=data.decode('utf-8', 'ignore')

    print(data_str)
```

The print statement throws:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2715' in position 149273: character maps to undefined
```

I thought the decode('utf-8', 'ignore') was supposed to ignore non utf-8 characters and leave it out of the result? How is it that I have a UnicodeEncodeError in the the print statement? How do I handle characters that can't encoded in Unicode? Thanks!

Comment: also why does: data_str=data.decode('ascii', 'ignore') work fine?

Comment: I thought it might be my pycharm console having a problem with the output. I tried printing to a file. Same error. `        file = open("/temp/test.txt", "w")
        file.write(data_str)`

Answer (score 1):

The error is caused by print (and any `file.write()`) not having a character map set and defaulting to ASCII.

The recommended approach is to set `PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8` in your environment or encode each string before printing:

```
print(`data_str`.encode("utf-8")
```

For file writing, set the encoding for the file when you open it:

```
file = open("/temp/test.txt", "w", encoding="UTF-8")
file.write('\u2715')
```